# Rails 5.1 ActiveAdmin error undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am receiving the errors below when I try to view two specific Models through ActiveAdmin's dashboard. Everything I've read points to a possible association issue, but I am not sure how to correct it. I see a lot of people having the same problems but haven't found any solutions to it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Listings#index
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

or

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Buildings#index
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

Models

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments, through: :listings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :listings, through: :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :buildings, through: :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :apointments, through: :listings
  has_many :listings, through: :buildings
  has_many :buildings
end

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies, through: :users
  has_many :users, through: :buildings
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :appointments
end

class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies, through: :users
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :appointments, through: :listings
  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
end


class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listing
  has_many :companies, through: :listings 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a typo in `has_many :apointments, through: :lisings`

Try using `has_many :appointments, through: :listings`

You have a missing p and a missing t

There is no resolution but https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4470 looks like your issue as well.

One other idea:

On the models that have `belong_to` and you use that association for a through, try changing it to singular. For example:

`class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listing
  has_many :companies, through: :listing # nb: singular here
end`

Perhaps that'll help?

Comment: Yes I caught that earlier and corrected, but still giving me the same error

Comment: Sanity checking here, did you restart your server after fixing the typos?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my server again to be sure and same error occured

Comment: Someone I know also suggested I singularize some of the associations and that also didn't work :(

Comment: If you boot up your app in `rails c` can you navigate all the associations?

Comment: HAHA, in my case I was using `singular` form of the relation